# I'm trying to implement windows.requestFileSystem under IE and FF

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, filesystems, internet-explorer-10

Is there a workaround to implement a sandbox for silent file open/save/delete operations under FF and IE? Chrome does have window.requestFileSystem and webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota, could it be possible to provide the same funcionality for the other two browsers using nothing else but Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's impossible to do it with javascript if browser does not support such functionality.

In case of firefox see https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/FileHandleAPI. I'm not sure that it's what you need, but maybe you will find something usefull there.